# Are any of the ruby VM's done using the LLVM toolchain?

Tags: ruby, llvm

I like the LLVM idea.  To be honest, I do not much care for Ruby, I'd rather use Perl, or Python, or .... ( it's a long list ).

Nothing personal, it's a great language, but I just prefer others.

However, Ruby has so many good ideas that I might need to STFU and just learn it, if nothing else to debug the tools.

Before I do so, I am wondering if there is a practical and usable implementation of Ruby done using the LLVM toolchain?

Comment: I believe there was one done with Parrot, which is sorta close

Comment: There are some. However, as with all alternative implementations of languages that used to have a single reference implementation not that long ago, there's always the (small, on a mature implementation) risk of minor but annoying incompabilities and a less mature ecosystem. You should just use the most popular and mature implementation for learning. You can always run (with perhaps minor porting effort) your code on another implementation later if you need its features (e.g. performance or JVM interop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have [llvmruby](http://llvmruby.org/wordpress-llvmruby/), [RubyComp](http://llvm.org/pubs/2004-Spring-AlexanderssonMSThesis.html) and more important, [Rubinius](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius), but [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/) also uses LLVM for "optimization passes, JIT and AOT compilation of Ruby expressions".